# Apple's Profile Manager (MDM) and Guided Access

Tags: ipad, mobile-device-management, profile-manager, guided-access

I have a few hundred iPads that are suddenly unable to enter Guided Access mode locally on the iPads. When we triple-click and triple-click is set to Guided Access, nothing happens. When I add something like voice-over to the triple-click functionality, I get the menu where I can select Guided Access (or voice-over), but again when tapping Guided Access nothing happens.

I'm fairly confident this is related to the restrictions we placed on the device group, but for the love of me I can't seem to figure out what restriction is stopping this from working. We don't have Single App Mode turned on due to the fact that the devices move between random wifi-networks and we need to be able to configure them on the device, but I added the apps that we need guided access for in the "Allow these apps to enter Single App Mode" list anyway, without that helping.

Which restriction is stopping us from entering Guided Access Mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a bug in iOS 8 (and 8.1). If you have guided access enabled when updating from iOS 7 it stops working. The fix is to turn it off, reboot the device, then turn it back on again.